# How to destroy a custom Control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I have a panel in my XML view

```
<panel id="abcd"> 
</panel>
```

This is my controller I am trying to add a custom Control as

```
someFunction() {
    if(this.customControl) {
        this.customControl.destroy();
    }
    var content = this.getView().byId("abcd");/*here panel object is received*/
    this.customControl = new someCustomControl(); /*here custom control is created*/
    content.addContent(customControl);/*here adding the control to panel*/
}
```

its getting added. Now next time I call this method I need to destroy this control and create a new one how to do it ??

Comment: Can you share a small demo of the same ?

Comment: Why would you remove it and then add it again?

Comment: <mvc:View>
 <l:HorizontalLayout>
  <l:content>
   <Button id="openMenu" text="Open Menu" press="handlePressOpenMenu" />
   </l:content>
 </l:HorizontalLayout>
</mvc:View>   and in my controller i want to add a custom control as given  handlePressOpenMenu: function(oEvent) {
  if(this.customControl)
{
this.customControl.destroy();
}
var content = this.getView().byId("abcd");
this.customControl = new my.someCustomControl(); 
content.addContent(customControl);
}

Comment: You may have destroyed the control, but the DOM reference still exists; you should also remove it from the panel's `content` aggregation. But then again, why would you destroy a control, and not simply hide/show it on demand?

Comment: ya thanks i got the solution as u said like remove from the aggregation..thanks